# Python - predict a manual value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, dataset

I've a dataset with 21 colums, and the N.11 is the column I want to predict.

My Dataset is structured in this mode:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]].values #Input features
y = dataset.iloc[:,11].values #Label to be predicted
```

and example of a row from dataset `X[:1]`

> [2.0, 4, 7, 14, 16, 12, 4, 15, 12, 1, 2, '45', '55', 15, 19, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3];

when I'm going to predict an manual data:

```
data = [1,4,8,23,8,13,7,9,20,1,3,'50','50',15,16,0,2,4,8,3,1];
new_prediction = lin.predict(sc.transform(np.array([data]).reshape(-1, 1)))
print("Prediction score:" , new_prediction)
```

i get back this error:

> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (21,1) doesn't
> match the broadcast shape (21,20)

becouse a missing column is a value that I want to predict.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My wrong. Data have more items than required